# Log in Logout history vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

How can i track or write my log in and time out history in my database (MSAccess) this is my code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = Nothing And TextBox2.Text = Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Enter Username and Password", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Else
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                con.Open()
            End If
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select count(*) from Admin where Username =? and Password=?", con)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
            Dim count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

            If (count > 0) Then
                MsgBox("    Login Success" & vbNewLine & "Hello Admin : " & TextBox1.Text, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                MsgBox("Time in : " + Date.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"))
                    Dim cmd2 As New OleDbCommand("Insert into AdminTime(User,TimeIn,TimeOut)values " & TextBox1.Text & Date.Now.ToString('hh:mm:ss')", con)
                Me.Hide()
                Form5.AdminLabel.Text = "   | Hello Admin : " + TextBox1.Text
                Form5.Show()
                TextBox2.Text = ""
            Else
                MsgBox("Access Denied", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

i want to know the right command that will insert the time in of my user

Comment: While @nanda9894 answers the question (missing ExecuteNonQuery), don't forget to use parameters with the second command object. You're doing it with the first OleDbCommand object, but didn't in the second.

Comment: What is the datatype of TimeIn and TimeOut in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want an `And` in your `TextBox` valadation code, if either of them is blank you don't want to proceed. Use a short circuited `OrElse`.

You should keep your database objects local so you can control that they are closed and disposed. You should not have to check on your connection state. Using...End Using blocks will ensure the objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error.

Although `OleDb` pays no attention to parameter names, only to the order they appear in the sql command matching the order they are added to the `Parameters` collection; I gave them names just to make the code more readable.

You have messed this line up to a 'fair thee well'.

```
Dim cmd2 As New OleDbCommand("Insert into AdminTime(User,TimeIn,TimeOut)values " & TextBox1.Text & Date.Now.ToString('hh:mm:ss')", con)
```

This is just one of the problems of not using Parameters. The other is to avoid Sql injection which is much more serious.

Of course, you should NEVER store passwords as plain text. The should be salted and hashed but that is beyond the scope of this question and I leave it to you to research this.

```
Private Sub OpCode()
    If TextBox1.Text = Nothing OrElse TextBox2.Text = Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Enter Username and Password", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    Else
        Dim count As Integer
        Using con As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string"),
                cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select count(*) from Admin where Username = @Username and Password= @Password;", con)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
            con.Open()
            count = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        End Using

        If (count > 0) Then
            MsgBox("Login Success" & vbNewLine & "Hello Admin : " & TextBox1.Text, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            MsgBox("Time in : " + Date.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"))
            Using con As New OleDbConnection("Your Connection String"),
                    cmd As New OleDbCommand("Insert into AdminTime (User,TimeIn,TimeOut) Values(@User, @TimeIn, @TimeOut);", con)
                ' & TextBox1.Text & ", con)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@User", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@TimeIn", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Date.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@TimeOut", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "Not Available"
                con.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
            Me.Hide()
            Form5.AdminLabel.Text = "   | Hello Admin : " + TextBox1.Text
            Form5.Show()
            TextBox2.Text = ""
        Else
            MsgBox("Access Denied", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

You will have to retrieve the primary key of your inserted record when you later go back and update it with the time out.

Assuming the name of the primary key column is Id...

```
Select Max(Id) From AdminTime Where User = @User And TimeOut = 'Not Available'
```

This log would be a lot more useful if the TimIn and TimeOut fields were DataTime fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
       Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = Nothing And TextBox2.Text = Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Enter Username and Password", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Else
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                con.Open()
            End If
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select count(*) from Admin where Username =? and Password=?", con)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
            Dim count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

            If (count > 0) Then
                MsgBox("    Login Success" & vbNewLine & "Hello Admin : " & TextBox1.Text, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                MsgBox("Time in : " + Date.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"))
                OleDbCommand cmd2= new OleDbCommand(); 
                cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
                cmd2.CommandText = "Insert into AdminTime(User,TimeIn,TimeOut)values ("&TextBox1.Text &","& Date.Now &",NULL)";
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
                Me.Hide()
                Form5.AdminLabel.Text = "   | Hello Admin : " + TextBox1.Text
                Form5.Show()
                TextBox2.Text = ""
            Else
                MsgBox("Access Denied", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: What if only one text box is empty? Do you want to proceed with the code?

Comment: Please use parameters ALL the time.